# Visual Studio Download is not working. Cannot find ISO File

Tags: visual-studio-2010, download

I have a dreamspark account, and I recently downloaded "visual studio 2010" for a class.

The unfortunate thing is that I cannot get the program to run.

I understand That I have to download the iso file, but i cannot find it.

It downloads to my desktop (as a winzip file) and I dont know what to do after that)
I am so lost on what to do.

Any help would be awesome. I need visual studio for a class assignment due Monday.

Comment: Unzip it with [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/win/en/index.htm) there should be an ISO in there and you can use that.

Comment: You could use WinRAR as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the installation process here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e2h7fzkw.aspx

Follow the steps one by one.